# I am confused about which point we should take moment of inertia (moi) in diff situations

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, moment-of-inertia

A uniform rod of mass m and length l is kept vertical with lower end clamped. It is slightly pushed to fall down under gravity. Find angular speed of rod when passing through its lowest position.

I used work energy theorem here, but I got it wrong. It says that moi should be taken wrt the clamped end. 
Why can't we take moi about center-of-mass as we are measuring potential energy change wrt it.
Any clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: Because MOI depends on the location of the axis of rotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to be consistent in your calculation of kinetic energy. At the pivot, since it does not move you have $$ KE = \frac{1}{2} I_{\rm pivot} \omega^2 $$

But you can consider the center of mass, and include the linear motion as well

$$ KE = \frac{1}{2} I_{\rm cm} \omega^2 + \frac{1}{2} m v_{\rm cm}^2 $$

You can easily show that both expressions will result in the same answer since

$$ \begin{aligned}
  v_{\rm cm} & = \omega d \\
  I_{\rm pivot} & = I_{\rm cm} + m d^2 
\end{aligned} $$

where $ d = \frac{\ell}{2}$ the distance between the pivot and the center of mass.

So your error wasn't the wrong point of calculating MMOI, but rather that you forgot to include the linear motion of the center of mass.

Answer (score 0):

One can calculate the sum of moments about any point you want, but there are usually a few (maybe only one) that will make the problem simple. In this case, as the rod rotates, the force acting on the rod at the pinned end (surely it's not clamped, but pinned -- there is a difference) will be changing and it is an unknown. If you choose to calculate the moments about the center of mass, then you have a time-dependent, unknown moment acting at that end. If you calculate the moments about the pinned end, the force there produces no moment, and the only moment results from the weight acting through the center of mass.

As far as calculating the moment of inertia, because the actual rotation is about the pinned end, that's the most obvious point to use for MOI. It's okay that the center of mass is moving.

It's a matter of convenience and simplicity.

And don't measure $\Delta PE$ with respect to a moving CoM in this problem, mainly because the CoM is accelerating, and doing mechanics in accelerating reference frames is tricky. It's much easier with a fixed point such as the pinned end, or even the *original* location of the CoM. Also, your reference frame origin does NOT have to be the calculation point for moments or MOI.